# unable to disable super key using xmodmap

Tags: xmodmap

I'm using xmodmap to disable the super key, but when i press some keys i.e. (M,A) the gnome shortcut for those keys (super+M, super+A) fires up, even without  press the super key.

looks like the super key is virtually pressed even when it's disabled by xmodmap.
this is my xmodmap file:

```
clear Lock
clear Control
clear Mod1
clear Mod2
clear Mod3
clear Mod4
clear Mod5
```

what can i do? i wanna use those keys normally.

Answer (score 0):

Open Terminal and type:

```
xev
```

With the new window in focus, press the **Super key** to get its keycode. Since you say its virtually pressed, type the following:

```
xmodmap -pk
```

I did that and my key code is 133 for Super_L and 134 for Super_R, may not be the same so do a check.

To disable a key type the following:

```
xmodmap -e 'keycode <number> = NoSymbol'
```

I doubt one of the super key has the issue, so perform the command for one key and check if the issue is resolved.

Comment: still not working

Comment: Did you change both the super keys ?

Comment: yes, I did, I'm thinking the problem is in the "clear" command.